# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined

Tags: jakarta-ee, junit

When i try to load my configuaration files in junit test class i am getting below error while injecting datasource:

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1079)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.getTransactionManager(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:308)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:158)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:358)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

Please Can anyone help me out in this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can not access "transactionManager". As I see, you do unit testings then I suppose you do not access the ApplicationContext.xml file (or whatever where your beans are declared).

For unit testings, you should give the bean files explicitly through annotations.

These annotations work for me:

```
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="transactionManager", defaultRollback=true)
@Transactional
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:applicationContext.xml",
    "classpath:applicationContext-dao.xml",
    "classpath:applicationContext-services.xml",
    "classpath:/com/xxx/zzz/test/CompanyServiceTest-context.xml"})
public class CompanyServiceTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {
private static Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(CompanyServiceTest.class);

@Autowired
public CompanyService companyService;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    System.err.println("Clear the mailboxes...");
    Mailbox.clearAll();
}

    @Test
    public void testCreateCompany() throws IOException, BusinessException, MessagingException {
        LOG.info("Creating the company DEMO...");
    }
```

}

Comment: which annotation can i use to load the bean classes??

Comment: Just added code. Depends how you handle the tests. Basically the class use a defaulted `<classname>-context.xml` bean file. Please look at [www.springbyexample.org](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/intro-to-ioc-unit-test-beans-from-application-context.html) for details.